# How to get elementById in Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using nativescript with vue.js and I'm trying to do something like DOM operation. This is sample code from my template:

```
<Label textWrap="true">
    <FormattedString id="formString"
      backgroundColor="yellow"
      effectiveHeight="100"
      effectiveWidth="100%">
      <Span text="This text has a " /> 
    </FormattedString>
 </Label>
```

I want to get tag element **FormattedString** by his id - **formString** 
 In javascript is like this:

`let fs = doument.getElementById('formString');`
How can I do this in Nativescript-Vue?
I know that there is library [nativescript-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-dom), but I don't want to use whole library for simple getById.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Label.getViewById("formString")` to access the attributes of FormattedString.

[getViewById](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#getviewbyid) is the nearest equivalent to the javascript getElementById

Hope this helps

Comment: e.g.  Label.getViewById(“formString”).backgroundColor would return yellow..

Comment: This totally works but still if you are on Vue, then using `ref` instead of `id` may be preferred.

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks for the fast answer. I was able to get element by this way:             `getElemBg(args) {
      const view = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view");
      let button = args.object;
      let parent = button.parent;

      let fstr = view.getViewById(parent, "formString");
      fstr.backgroundColor;
     }`